# Method to trigger a php script from the server on particular schedule without using cron job facility

Tags: php

As my server is not supporting cron job, I want a file in my server to trigger its action on a particular time every day..

Please let me know whether it possible to do run a script at a particular time from the server side itself without any external act.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start script without ANY external act.

If your file server has SSH or HTTP server or something like that, you can configure cron job on another server to start your script via SSH / HTTP / something like that.

Also, you can create PHP script, which would do sleeping in a loop all the time, and wake up and do some job only if current time is near some specific value. You will have to correct maximum execution time for php script (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for details), and you will have to start your script on server startup. BTW, this does not look like good solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (rand(0,100)==0){
    if (!file_exists($tf='tmp/job.crontime') || (time() - filemtime($tf))>(60*60*24)){
        ... # your tasks
        touch($tf);
        }
    }
```

This simple & stupid script uses a file to store the time of last job-ecexution. If `>60*60*24` has passed — it launches the job code. `rand(0,100)` should lower the overhead of checking for jobs on each request: `1/100` is the chance of running your jobs.

Put it in the end of your 'index.php'. Don't use in projects with modelate to high load :))

The Great Disadvantage: it won't run if you don't have any visitors.

---

**UPD:** Write a script that runs indefinitely and every 30s does `touch('tmp/job.crontime')` to report it's still alive. It should also check the current time & perform actions.

In index.php, if more than 30s has passed — re-launch the daemon with an HTTP-request. Ugly, but fully functional. You'll also deal with time limits, be careful!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kel's answer.

You could try out one of the free cronjob services available, if your server doesn't support it.

- [Online Cronjobs](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/)
- [Set Cronjob](http://www.setcronjob.com/)

Just the first two found on Google, there's likely to be more if you search a little.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, this is not possible literally "without external act".

A nice solution I found in the ThinkUp software (don't know where else this is used) to use a RSS feed reader. From the point of simplicity, this is probably the best option.

The idea is that you use your feed reader to automatically call a script on your site every XX hours (or whatever interval you want). When called, this script executes the maintenance tasks or whatever it is that you want to do.

To make sure that not everybody can run that script and cause your server to break down (I suppose this is a somewhat heavy task), you can use a unique long identifier string appended as URL parameter to make sure that the script only gets called by you.

Other than that, you can use one of the "poor man's" web cron job services that have been suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is on a public web server and you have enough visits, you could always use those to run code to check for a given value, say hour of day, number of times a file have been accessed (or store your number in a file). Just put your php code on top of a web page.